# AngularJS Single page app: google maps reloading weirdness

Tags: css, angularjs, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I am trying to build a angular single page app for mobile that uses a map on one page. It also should include a sticky footer, and is based on bootstrap.  The sticky footer css interferes with the css needed to get the map to take up all of the remaining screen space, so I add a class='map' to the html element to override certain css elements (see below).

Everything works nicely until I go to the map page, leave it and then return to the map page. In this instance the map is not working correctly at all.  It is hard to describe, so please try the [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6Dx6xXS3FkBfZTWK5psZ?p=preview).

I have found CSS that works for the map reloading, but then that breaks something else in the site.  It is driving me crazy trying to combine the two models, hence my appeal for help.

Update: I have now found that resizing the screen rectifies the rendering issues, until you leave and return to the map. Of course a mobile use cannot change their screen size, but this may help find a solution.

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

html.map {
    height: 100%
}

body {
    /* Margin bottom by footer height */
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.map body {
    /* For Google map */
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    padding-top: 60px           
}

footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ccc;
    height: 60px;
    top: 0;
}

.map header {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I implemented a solution similar to yours, which I found in [this blog article](http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/google-maps-in-hidden-div). Essentially, you have to trigger a resize event in order to have the map repainted correctly when it goes from hidden to visible.

But I put my code into a directive instead of a controller (doesn't bloat controller and decorates the element it affects), instead of adding a watcher it runs only after the directive/element is linked (more performant), and it doesn't require you to re-enter your coordinates in order to refresh:

```
.directive('autoRefresh', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            $timeout(function(){
                var center = scope.map.getCenter();
                google.maps.event.trigger(scope.map, "resize");
                scope.map.setCenter(center);  
            });
        }
    }
})
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bXUBjdLPtQFQluXsQvtg?p=preview)

Comment: I tried you Plunker and added the suggestion to my local code, but it did not change anything

Comment: Updated - I misunderstood the original problem

Comment: Wow - so I have an attribute directive attached to an element directive. The docs don't really explain what $timeout does when no delay is set, so I wonder whey $timeout is needed. Does link fire after the dom is loaded?

Comment: You can think of this attribute directive as a decorator - it just adds some functionality to an existing element. `$timeout` is just an Angular wrapper for `setTimeout`. Here, even without a delay, it will cause what's contained in the function passed to it to run after the browser renders.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so what I was missing was to trigger the resize event.  This now works perfectly in my plunker but not yet in my more complex actual code.  Nearly there!

```
restosApp.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('map', function() {
        google.maps.event.trigger($scope.map, 'resize');
        var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(52.374, 4.899);
        $scope.map.setCenter(ll);
    });
});
```